# jquery ui not showing close button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Created code for using jquery-UI box

```
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-corner-all ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-draggable-handle">
   <span id="ui-id-54" class="ui-dialog-title">Session expired</span>
   <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" title="Close"><span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span>Close</button>
</div>
```

when using in internet explorer it select the different image and show the cross button but in chrome, it doesn't show the cross button for the image, but when another image is selected from developer tools it shows the image

```
.ui-button .ui-icon {
  background-image: url(images/ui-icons_777777_256x240.png);
}

.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {
  background-image: url(images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png)!important;
}
```

Comment: give width and height of the image

Comment: share the code in fiddle.